# Where is the bash key binding done for esc-esc (which loads completion suggestions)

Tags: bash, shell

When pressing Esc-Esc, bash lists all the possible completion suggestions. Where is the key binding for this function done?

(When I updated to bash 4 on OS X, this function got bound to tab instead, and I'd like to disable it.

It is not in my bashrc or bash_profile.

Disabling bash-completion does not help either since this feature does not need bash-completion.

`bind -p` does not list this binding either.)

Answer (score 2):

The default key bindings are compiled into bash.

If you want to change a key binding, you can put the override either into some bash interactive startup file, or into the readline init file (normally `.inputrc` in your home directory)